# .Net SQL database does not recognize model variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I am working with a `.Net` API project. The trouble is, that I have a kind of slow computer and I was working with `VS 2013`. After some time I installed `VS 2015`, and it worked perfectly until I removed `VS 2013`. Besides, the uninstallation of `VS 2013` was pretty difficult, because I had to follow up this guide: [Cannot uninstall, install or repair Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/735811/cannot-uninstall-install-or-repair-visual-studio-2012-2013) (download whole setup, and use command line). Now problem is that now SQL server does not accept ManagerIds and WorkerIds that I pass.
My document class:

```
 public class ConstructionSite
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public List<int> ManagerIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> WorkerIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
 }
```

But when I hit "Show table data" button, it only gives me this type of view:
[image: a busy cat]

I tried to change Configuration.cs class Seed method like this:

```
protected override void Seed(ReportRest.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    context.ConstructionSites.AddOrUpdate(new ConstructionSite
    {
        CreatorId = 2,
        CreatedAt = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01),
        IsActive = false,
        ManagerIds = new List<int> {1},
        WorkerIds = new List<int> {2},
    });
}
```

Then I removed existing Migrations folder, opened Nugget Package Manager Console and fired these commands:
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration First
Update-Database.
Unfortunately, that hadn't helped me to recover ManagerIds and WorkerIds. So, before messing with unstable Microsoft setups, I would like to ask you if there is a way to remind my database of forgotten variables. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Unfortunately, that hadn't helped me to recover missed columns". Which colums do you refer?

Comment: I am Missing ManagerIds and WorkerIds columns. Sorry for not specifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not realy sure what columns your are missing, since all 4 normal columns are shown in database and the both lists should normaly be stored in own database-tables.

But if you use the default setup with ASP.net and EntityFramework and you already had a Migrations-folder, there should be also a "__MigrationHistory"-Table in database.

Means, if you deleted the old Migrationsfolder, your are also needed to delete the entries of the table. After that you can create an new "Add-Migration InitialCreate" and should get a whole first Migration of your current code base.

// For creating the new initial Datbase-Update to get a working migration for future changes:

1. Add the new Migration,
2. then cut the content of Up() and Down() Methode from new the migration file
3. Run Update-Database (to create the entry for __MigrationHistory-table)
4. Strg-Z in the migration-file to backup the original content
5. After that you are able to run Add-Migration and Update-Database for future changes of your Models

Comment: I am Missing ManagerIds and WorkerIds columns. Sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: ManagerIds and WorkerIds are no Columns of ConstructionSites.
There should be 2 more tables named ManagerIds and WorkerIds  in your Database with foreign keys to your ConstructionSites-table.

You simply can't store multiple Values in one database-cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one-to-may relations to Managers and Workers, you have to create something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ConstructionSite> ConstructionSites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext()
        : base("YourConnectionStringName")
    {

    }
}

public class ConstructionSite
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public List<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ConstructionSiteId { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ConstructionSiteId { get; set; }
}
```

This creates relations you want

Comment: Yes, I will use this approach. Thank you.